# mysql load data infile inserting double quotes

Tags: php, mysqli

Hi I know this question is not only for the sake of mine but for the sake of everyone who uses a mysql LOAD DATA INFILE.

I just want to know why I am receiving this ("") double quotes every time I import data using load data infile? the data from csv has been successfully added in database but in instance there's a double quotes within the value. for example.

"value1"  | "value2"  | "value3"

Any help? here's my mysql script.

```
echo $mysql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$path ."' 
        REPLACE INTO TABLE table
        FIELDS 
            TERMINATED BY ',' 
        LINES 
            TERMINATED BY '\\n'
        IGNORE 1 LINES 
        (`column1`, `column2`, `column3`, `column4`..)";

        $query = mysqli_query($link, $mysql) or die(mysqli_error($link));
```

Thanks

Comment: not that I have corrected it totally. I had to use ENCLOSED BY '\"' with the backslash BUT then it skipped every other line. So now I am looking to see if I can figure out that too. If I do I will post it. IF you do, please update so I can figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am guessing from your question that your infile values are something along the lines of this,

```
"column1","column2","column3","column4"
"column1a","column2a","column3a","column4a"
```

Since in your mysql statement you have only stated that the fields are terminated by a `,` it will read a value upto the mysql engine finding a `,`, hence the qoutes.

The mysql syntax for declaring if fields are enclosed by something is exactly like below;

```
FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"'
```

Your new query would look like,

```
"LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$path ."' 
    REPLACE INTO TABLE table
    FIELDS 
        TERMINATED BY ',',
        ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES 
        TERMINATED BY '\\n'
    IGNORE 1 LINES 
    (`column1`, `column2`, `column3`, `column4`..)"
```

This tells the mysql engine to look for the characters in between the `"` and take that value as the field value.

You can read more about it on the mysql website.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Hope this helped!

Comment: i receive  syntax error, unexpected '' ' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in

Comment: Try a comma after fields terminated by, my mysql is rusty, I'll update my answer

Comment: You need to escape " . So ENCLOSED BY `'\"'`